# icons must be visible at different view level

Tags: icons, size, openstreetmap, openlayers

I use openlayers3 to build an application

I would like to change the zoomlevel icons are visible at

https://bestofosm.org/?lon=4.0798&lat=50.9136&zoom=15#interesting-het-loo-garden

for example

if you go to London you see airports are visible at zoomlevel 10

lets say I want all touristic icons visible at zoomlevel 10
and airport icons at zoomlevel 15
is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking about your own markers or about the icons from the OSM map tiles?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to put your markers in different layers and give each layer a minResolution and maxResolution. When the map zooms outside these resolutions the layers will automatically become hidden. Something like:

```
var touristicIcons = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: touristicIconsSource,
    minResolution: xx
    maxResolution: xx
});

// Repeat for airports layer, with different resolutions
```

Writing down a zoom level as a resolution will not work. You will need to find out what resolution belongs to your desired zoom level. The easiest way to do this is with this little hack, that logs the zoom level and resolution every time you scroll through the map:

```
map.getView().on('change:resolution', function (event) {
    var view = event.currentTarget;
    console.log('Zoom: ' + view.getZoom() + 
                ', resolution: ' + view.getResolution());
});
```